Prove that the sum of squares of distances from the vertices of an equilateral triangle to a line is dependent only on its distance from the centroid.
I was reading about the moment of inertia of a triangular plate and stumbled upon some properties which directly imply the fact that the sum of squares of distances from the vertices of an equilateral triangle to a line is dependent only on the distance of the line from its centroid. However, I have not been able to find or come up with a purely geometric proof of it. (I feel a proof using analytical geometry, complex numbers or trigonometry is rather trivial).
I tried considering the special case where the line passes through the centroid itself but couldn't proceed furthur.
On the recommendation of @Blue, I have added the following proof of this property using analytical geometry:
Let us call the equilateral triangle ABC. Set the origin of an orthogonal xy co- ordinate system at the centroid of the triangle and, without loss of generality, set $(0,a/\sqrt3)$ as A, $(-a/2,-a/(2\sqrt3))$ as B and $(a/2,-a/(2\sqrt3))$ as C. (The side length of the equilateral triangle is a)
Now, let us assume a random line L in the co- ordinate plane with the equation:$ px + qy + r = 0$. Let us denote $L(x,y)=px + qy + r$.
The square of distance of A from L is $(L_A)^2 = (L(0,a/\sqrt3))^2 = ((aq/\sqrt3) + r)^2/(p^2 + q^2)$.
Similarly, the square of the distance of B from L is $(L_B)^2$ and the square of the distance of C from L is :
$(L_A)^2 + (L_B)^2 + (L_C)^2$
$= (L(0,a/\sqrt3)^2 + (L(-a/2,-a/(2\sqrt3)))^2 + (L(a/2,-a/(2\sqrt3)))^2$
$= ((aq/\sqrt3) + r)^2 + ((-ap/2) - (aq/(2\sqrt3)) + r)^2 + ((ap/2) - (aq/(2\sqrt3)) + r)^2)/(p^2 + q^2)$
$= \frac{(aq)^2 + (ap)^2)/2) + 3r^2)}{(p^2 + q^2)}$
$= ((a^2)/2) + 3((L(0,0))^2)$
Thus, if the distance of a random line from the centroid of an equilateral triangle is represented by d and the side length of the equilateral triangle is represented by a, then, the sum of the squares of the distances of the vertices of the triangle from the line is represented by $3d^2 + ((a^2)/2)$.
I request you to help me by providing a purely geometric proof of this property of equilateral triangles.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Since an analytic/trigonometric proof is likely to be trivial, please provide one. It may serve as a jumping-off point for others to find a synthetic solution (for instance, by showing expressly how the sum-of-squared-distances relates the distance-to-centroid), without anyone having to spend time duplicating that effort. ... Good luck!

I have edited my original post. I apologise as I don't know how to format it well.

I believe this is a duplicate, but the top answer in the question I remember still used coordinate to some extent, but it was highly simplified to a couple of lines of calculations only. Sadly, it is difficult to search for geometry, so I can't find it now


This is a simple model which may be used for a general solution. As can be see in the picture the line L intersect two sides of the triangle, we have:
$\triangle EFG\sim \triangle EKC$
$EF=\frac {2GH}3$
$BH=\frac {a\sqrt 3}2\Rightarrow GH=\frac13 EK=\frac 13 \cdot\frac {a\sqrt 3}2\Rightarrow EF=\frac23\cdot \frac 13\frac {a\sqrt3}2=\frac{a\sqrt3}9$
Also:
$DF=GB=\frac23\times \frac{a\sqrt3}2$
In the right angled triangle GDE we have:
$d_G^2=GF^2=FE\times DF=\frac{a\sqrt3}9\times \frac23\times \frac{a\sqrt3}2=\frac{a^2}9$
$d_G=\frac a3$
$d_C=CK=HC-(HK=GF)=\frac a2-\frac 23=\frac a6$
$d_B=GF=\frac a3$
$d_A=a-\frac a6=\frac{5a}6$
Hence  with these values we have:
$$S=d_A^2+d_B^2+d_C^2=\frac{5a^2}6$$
$a^2=9d_G^2$
So we finally get:
$$S=d_A^2+d_B^2+d_C^2=\frac 56\times 9d_G^2=\frac{15}2 d_G^2$$
If the line L' is parallel with L at a distance like $d$ we have a simple linear transformation. If   L' has an angle like $\alpha$ with L we will have an angular transformation, but we finally get $S$ as a function of $D_G$.
Also we have:
$d_G=\frac 13(d_A+d_B+d_C)$
Squaring both sides we get:
$d_G^2=\frac 19(d_A^2+d_B^2+d_C^2)+\frac 29(d_Ad_B+d_Bd_C+d_Cd_A)$
Let $d_Ad_B+d_Bd_C+d_Cd_A=m$
For this particular case we have:
$d_G^2(1-\frac{15}{18})=\frac 29 m$
Which gives:
$m=\frac 34 d_G^2$
However $m$ depends on magnitudes of $d_A$, $d_B$ and $d_C$.


We hope to show that OP’s statement is true for an arbitrary line $PQ$ shown in the diagram. Line $PQ$, which is positioned at a distance of $d$ from the centroid $G$ of $ABC$, intersects $A-$median of the equilateral triangle $ABC$ at $U_0$. To achieve our goal, we need to prove first the same statement for the line $MN$, which runs parallel to the side $BC$ of $\triangle ABC$ and passes through $U_0$. Line $MN$ is positioned at a distance $d_0$ from $G$. For brevity, denote the length of $GD$ by $a$. With that, we have $AG$=2a$.
According to the diagram, the distances to the line $MN$ from the three vertices $A$, $B$, and $C$ of $\triangle ABC$ are $AU_0$, $BV_0$ and $CW_0$ respectively. They can be expressed as functions of $a$ and $d_0$ as shown below.
$$AU_0 =2a-d_0,\qquad BV_0 =CW_0 =a+d_0$$
Therefore, the sum of the squares of these three distances, can be written as,
$$AU_0^2+BV_0^2+CW_0^2=\left(2a-d_0\right)^2+2\left(a+d_0\right)^2=6a^2+3d_0^2.\tag{1}$$
Equation (1) clearly indicates that, for a given equilateral triangle, the sum of the squares of the three distances in question depends only on $d_0$.
Now, we divert our attention to the abovementioned arbitrary line $PQ$, which lies distances $AU$, $BV$, $CW$, and $GT$ from $A$, $B$, $C$ and $G$ respectively. By the way, $P$ and $Q$ are the points of intersection of $PQ$ with $BV_0$ and extended $CW_0$ respectively. In our quest to find an expression similar to (1) for $PQ$, we use the theorems Euclid I.26 (congruent triangle), Euclid I.47 (Theorem of Pythagoras) and Euclid VI.4 (similar triangles). For brevity, denote the length of $PV_0$ by $h$.
Since $U_0TG$ is a right-angled triangle, we apply Theorem of Pythagoras to express $U_0T$ in terms of $d_0$ and $d$.
$$U_0T=\sqrt{d_0^2-d^2}\tag{2}$$
The triangle pair $U_0V_0P$ and $U_0TG$ are inversely similar. Hence, using (2), we can express $h^2$ in terms of $a$, $d$, and $d_0$.
$$\dfrac{PV_0}{ U_0T}=\dfrac{ U_0V_0}{GT}\quad\longrightarrow\quad h=\sqrt{d_0^2-d^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{d} \quad\longrightarrow\quad h^2=3a^2\left(\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2-1\right)\tag{3}$$
The triangle pair $U_0V_0P$ and $CZB$ are also inversely similar. So, we can derive an expression for $CZ$ in terms of $h$, $d$ and $d_0$.
$$\dfrac{CZ}{PV_0}=\dfrac{BZ}{U_0V_0}\quad\longrightarrow\quad CW-BV=CW-ZW= CZ= h\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}a\dfrac{d}{d_0}}{\sqrt{3}a}=2h\dfrac{d}{d_0}\tag{4}$$
Triangles $U_0TG$ and $U_0UA$ are similar. Therefore,
$$AU_0 =AU\dfrac{d_0}{d}.\tag{5}$$
Since $PVB$ and $U_0TG$ are similar triangles, we have $BP=BV\dfrac{d_0}{d}$. Hence, it follows that,
$$BV_0=BP+PV_0 =BP+h= BV\dfrac{d_0}{d}+h.\tag{6}$$
Since $V_0U_0=U_0W_0$, the pair of similar triangles $U_0V_0P$ and $U_0W_0Q$ are congruent as well. Therefore, the pair of corresponding sides $QW_0$ and $PV_0 $ are also equal. This means that $QW_0=h$. Since $QWC$ and $U_0TG$ are similar triangles, we have $CQ=CW\dfrac{d_0}{d}$. Therefore,
$$CW_0=CQ-QW_0 =CQ-h= CW\dfrac{d_0}{d}-h.\tag{7}$$
Now, we can replace the terms on the left hand side of (1) using (5), (6), and (7) to obtain,
$${\small{ \left[AU^2\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2\right]+ \left[BV^2\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2+BV\left(2h\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)+h^2\right]+ \left[CW^2\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2-CW\left(2h\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)+h^2\right]=6a^2+3d_0^2}}.$$
As shown below, to make the sum of the squares of distances in question the subject, we need to bring some of the terms from the left hand side to the right hand side after simplifying the above equation.
$$ \left(AU^2+BV^2+CW^2\right)\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2=  6a^2+3d_0^2+\left(CW-BV\right) \left(2h\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)-2h^2$$
Once we replace the term $(CW-BV)$ using (4), further simplification of the above equation is possible.
$$ \left(AU^2+BV^2+CW^2\right)\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2=  6a^2+3d_0^2+2h\dfrac{d}{d_0} \left(2h\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)-2h^2= 6a^2+3d_0^2+2h^2$$
Finally, we make use of (3) to eliminate $h^2$ and then to get to the solution.
$$ \left(AU^2+BV^2+CW^2\right)\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2= 6a^2+3d_0^2+6a^2\left(\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2-1\right)=6a^2\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2+3d_0^2$$
$$AU^2+BV^2+CW^2=\left(6a^2\left(\dfrac{d_0}{d}\right)^2+3d_0^2\right) \left(\dfrac{d}{d_0}\right)^2=6a^2+3d^2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
We think that the case, in which $PQ$ passes through centroid of $\triangle ABC$, must be explained separately to make this proof rigorous. It is up to OP to do the necessary explaining.
